# Infopath to pdf conversion in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I need to create an infopath document from a infopath form with entries fetched from a list. Then I need to convert this document to a pdf and store it in an document library. I have to do it in a **sharepoint autohosted app** that shall be deployed in the cloud version of sharepoint.

Can anyone suggest good approaches to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you have to convert it into word then from Word to convert it into PDF using word automation services.

Check this link, it is for SharePoint 2010 but same services available in 2013 and also you will get the direction.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/191775.aspx

Comment: Is there any way to convert infopath to word without using a third party tool?

Comment: the book which is mentioned in the article have the code how to convert it from infopath to word. another method is workflow if you want http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/videos/convert-infopath-form-to-word.htm